# Relation between mod 2 Betti numbers and integral cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be an orientable connected manifold of finite type. My question is that if $H^{i}(M,\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ is non-zero, then can we say that $H^{i}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ is non-zero? I know that this is not true for non-orientable manifold. For example $\mathbb{R}\text{P}^{2n}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that "$H^i(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ non-zero $\implies H^i(M;\mathbb{Z})$ non-zero" does not necessarily hold: note that this statement is equivalent to "$H^i(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong0 \implies H^i(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong0$." However, if we take $M$ to be the orientable $5$-manifold $\mathbb{R}P^5$, then for $i=3$ we indeed have $H^3(\mathbb{R}P^5,\mathbb{Z})\cong0$, but by the UCT
\begin{align}
H^3(\mathbb{R}P^5;\mathbb{Z}/2) &\cong \text{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(H_2(\mathbb{R}P^5;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(H_3(\mathbb{R}P^5;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}/2)\\
&\cong \text{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(0,\mathbb{Z}/2) \oplus \text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/2,\mathbb{Z}/2)\\
&\cong \mathbb{Z}/2,
\end{align}
which is non-zero. I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This can fail already for $i = 1$.

It follows from the Universal Coefficient Theorem that $H^1(M; G) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(M), G)$ for any abelian group $G$. There are many groups which admit a non-zero homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but not to $\mathbb{Z}$. So any orientable manifold whose fundamental group is such a group will demonstrate that your question has a negative answer.

**Example:** For any $n > 0$, the manifold $\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}$ is orientable with $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ so $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ while $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_2, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

---

In general, if $H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) \neq 0$ and $H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, then $H^{i+1}(M; \mathbb{Z}) \neq 0$. To see this, note that by the Universal Coefficient Theorem, we have

$$0 \to \operatorname{Ext}(H_{i-1}(M; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}) \to H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Hom}(H_i(M; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}) \to 0$$

If $H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, then $H_{i-1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free and $H_i(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is torsion. By the Universal Coefficient Thereom for $H^i(M; \mathbb{Z})$, we see that $H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_i(M; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}_2)$. So if $H^i(M; \mathbb{Z}_2) \neq 0$, then $H_i(M; \mathbb{Z}) \neq 0$. Now by the Universal Coefficient Theorem for $H^{i+1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$, there is an injection $\operatorname{Ext}(H_i(M; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}) \to H^{i+1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$. Since $H_i(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is a non-zero torsion group, we see that $\operatorname{Ext}(H_i(M; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}) \neq 0$ and hence $H^{i+1}(M; \mathbb{Z}) \neq 0$.

**Example:** For $n > 0$, it was observed in the previous example that $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}; \mathbb{Z}_2) \neq 0$ and $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$. In this case, we have $H^2(\mathbb{RP}^{2n+1}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \neq 0$.